# tweetsharp search

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

i am using tweetsharp to search for public posts.
I am using following code to search:

```
TwitterSearchResult tsr = Service.Search(new SearchOptions() { Q = keyword, Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Mixed, IncludeEntities=false});
```

Here is my question, why do i not get the same result from the api as on the twitter website.
If i use for example "redbull" as keyword i get totally different tweets from the twitter website as i received from tweetsharp.

Kind Regards
Manu

Answer (score 1):

var results = Servis.Search(new SearchOptions { Q ="cnn", Count =30 , Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Mixed, IncludeEntities = false });

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are 3 ways twitter can return stuff in search:
Recent (most recent posts that contains search term)
Popular (most popular posts that contains search term)
Mixed (most diversified result)

Try using this bit of code:

```
TwitterSearchResult tsr = Service.Search(new SearchOptions() { Q = keyword, Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Recent});
```